# Pandas idxmax() returns 0 if no value matches condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of `idxmax()`.

I'm using `idxmax()` to get all rows below the first row meeting a condition in a dataframe, like this:

`df = df[df['A'].gt(0).idxmax():]`

I'm then checking if the resulting dataframe is empty. There's one unit test where I expect an empty dataframe (no row meets the condition), but it was never empty, so I looked into it.

I found that if the condition is NEVER met, idxmax() returns 0 (instead of, say, `None` or instead of throwing an exception I could catch) - which clashes with the case where the condition **IS MET at row 0**.

Here's an example of what I'm seeing:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[0, 0, 0, 0]})  # no element where gt(0) is True
print("Truths values\n", df['A'].gt(0))     # checking the truth values of the Series
print("Index of first row where 'A' is at 0: ", df['A'].gt(0).idxmax())
```

The dataframe:

[image: First dataframe]

The execution result:

```
>>> Truth values
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False

Index of first row where 'A' is at 0: 0   <--- ???
```

And with a different dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[1, 0, 0, 0]})
print("Truths values\n", df['A'].gt(0))
print("Index of first row where 'A' is at 0", df['A'].gt(0).idxmax())
```

The dataframe:

[image]

The execution result:

```
Truth values
0    True
1    False
2    False
3    False

Index of first row where 'A' is at 0: 0
```

So we end up with the same behaviour for two different inputs.

My current solution: summing over 'A' and checking if the sum is 0, and doing something different if that's the case - which seems a bit overkill.

Am I using `idxmax()` wrong ? Could someone shed some light on this, as the behaviour seems very counter-intuitive ?

Thanks :)

Comment: The behavior seems okay. `df['A'].gt(0)` is four Falses (i.e. zeroes), so the zeroth index is the first largest value...

Comment: But idxmax() doesn't evaluate booleans, it just checks evaluated booleans (in my case, is a value strictly superior to 0) and should return the index of the first row where a boolean evaluated to True. Because if I follow your logic, how do you differentiate the case where your condition has been met in row 0, or the case where it was never met ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Series.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) will return the first row label of maximum value if multiple values equal the maximum.

[image]

Therefore, in following dataframe, index `0` will be returned for `Series.idxmax` since all `False` equals.

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
```

In following dataframe, index `0` will be returned for `Series.idxmax` since `True` is the maxiumn value. (In Python, `True` is large than `False`, you can print the result of `True > False`)

```
0    True
1    False
2    False
3    False
```

---

In your `df = df[df['A'].gt(0).idxmax():]`, you are actually selecting columns with index slice. If you want to select rows, you need use `df.loc[df['A'].gt(0).idxmax():]`

Comment: Oh I see, my mistake - thank you !